# How to update multiple fields in a row in phantom-dsl?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am using Phantom 1.26.6.

```
// id is the primary key
case class Motorcycle(id:String, model:String, made:String, capacity:Int)
```

Give an instance of Motorcycle, which already exists in Cassandra, I would
like to update the value of model, made, capacity.

```
// The following does not compile.
 update.where(_.id.eqs(bike.id)).modify(_.model.setTo(bike.model))
 .modify(_.make.setTo(bike.make))
 .modify(_.capacity.setTo(bike.capacity))


 // The following works.   
 val updateQuery = update.where(_.id.eqs(bike.id))

 for {
    _ <- updateQuery.modify(_.model.setTo(bike.model)).future()
    _ <- updateQuery.modify(_.make.setTo(bike.made)).future()
    result <- updateQuery.modify(_.capacity.setTo(bike.capacity)).future()
  } yield (result)
```

I wonder if there ia a better way of updating multiple fields.

Thanks in advance for any assistance !

Shing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the `and` operator to chain multiple update statements. This will execute everything in a single query.

```
 val updateQuery = update.where(_.id eqs bike.id)
   .modify(_model setTo bike.model)
   .and(_.make setTo bike.made)
   .and(_.capacity setTo bike.capacity)
   .future()
```